# My project had a problem executing 'react-native log-android'

Tags: react-native

My project had a problem executing `react-native log-android`, check the following error:

```
D:\SVN\ReactNative\ZYJJ>react-native log-android
info Starting logkitty
error Command failed: 'D:\Android\SDK/platform-tools/adb' logcat -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too, I can't solve the problem. My workaround is,

```
$ adb logcat
```

Comment: I still can't solve the problem, So here's my solution : Go to my androidsdk directory and open monitor.exe to see logs